# React test the Typography Text Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that has a link on it. I want to test the text value of the link.

```
     <Link  onClick={() => history.push(`/cars/`)}>
       <Typography id= "car-reviews">{carCount()}</Typography>
    </Link>
```

The test code as follows,

```
const wrapper = mount(<AssignedCars />);
const displayLabel = wrapper.find({id:'car-reviews'}).first();
expect(displayLabel.text).toBe('0');
```

But this fails, carCount() is returning 0 but I need to know how to test the text of the Typography object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `text` is a function and you need to invoke it in order to get the `text` value you're looking to test.

i.e.

```
const wrapper = mount(<AssignedCars />);
const displayLabel = wrapper.find({id:'car-reviews'}).first();
expect(displayLabel.text()).toBe('0');
```

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/text.html